# IndexError: list assignment index out of range for arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I think n begins at 0 and it will increase up till the last element on stack1.

```
arraylength = 3*stack1length
array = [0]*arraylength
for n in stack1:
    array[3*n] = stack1[n]
```

my array length is 3 times the length of stack1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for n in stack1:
```

Goes through the *items* in stack1.

You seem to be wanting to go through the indexes:

```
for n in range(len(stack1)):
    array[3*n] = stack1[n]
```

Note that this is better written with the convenience function, `enumerate`,

```
for n, stack1_n in enumerate(stack1):
    array[3*n] = stack1_n
```

Additionally, you can use some evil hackz:

```
array[::3] = stack1
```

`array[::3]` is every third item in `array` (`start:stop:step`), and therefore you're setting every third item to the corresponding item in `stack1`.

Comment: I don't think that's evil hacks. I would consider that Pythonic. haha

Comment: Haven't you heard? Python *is* an evil hack. A sweet, juicy hack upon hacks. ;)